# How to resolve Uncaught ReferenceError: COLLECTION is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1 in Meteor.js/MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am taking a full stack course via Eduonix.com. It seems that some of the code syntax is deprecated, as I have had to install older versions of multiple things to get through some of the sections. This did not help when I came to the Meteor.js section, so I installed the most recent and did some searching that allowed me to get through the first lesson. I tried the same for the second lesson (when I encountered this error), but have not had any luck with anything I have found.

I get this error when I try to use

```
todos.find().fetch()
```

in the browser's console.

**Relevant File Structure:**

```
client
--main.html
--main.js
lib
--collections.js
```

[View on github](https://github.com/CarsonBarry/FullStack-Course/tree/master/8-Meteor.js/Template/quicktodos)

In the course lesson, the line

```
import { Todos } from '../lib/collections';
```

is not present in **main.js** and the line

```
export const Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
```

in **collections.js** is presented as

```
Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
```

I have tried changing

```
import { Todos } from '../lib/collections';
```

to

```
import { Todos } from '/lib/collections';
```

but it did nothing.

I have also tried just adding

```
Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
```

to **main.js**, but I got an error that said "todos" was already defined (only to get the same undefined error when I tried to run the console command, because somehow it was both already defined and is still undefined).

I have made these changes based on looking up similar issues online before making this post, hoping that it would save me like adding

```
import './main.html';
```

to **main.js** did when I was getting a similar undefined error related to that prior to this error.

**main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>QuickTodos</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<Template name="main">
  <header>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </header>
  <ul>
    {{#each todos}}
      {{> todo}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="todo">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</Template>
```

**main.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import './main.html';
import { Todos } from '../lib/collections';

const todos = [
  {text:'Pickup kids from school'},
  {text:'Go food shopping'},
  {text:'Meeting with boss'}
];

Template.main.helpers({
  title(){
    return 'QuickTodos';
  },
  todos(){
    return todos;
  }
});
```

**collections.js**

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
```

When I run

```
todos.find().fetch()
```

I expect to get an empty array, but instead I get:

```
VM1905:1 
Uncaught ReferenceError: todos is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that the capitalization of these two lines are different, meaning they will point to different variables (thus, todos is not defined):

```
export const Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
todos.find().fetch()
```

The second thing, is that because Meteor uses CommonJS modules, any variables you declare will be local to that module, and won't be available on the console.
(there's some exceptions, like the `Todos` declared without `var`, `let`, or `const`, which will be scoped across the whole application, but still not global or available in the console)

You can force a variable to be global by adding it as a property to the `window`:

```js
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const Todos = new Mongo.Collection('todos');
window.Todos = Todos; // here we make it global
```

And then as long as this file is imported by `client/main.js`, you can use `Todos` on the console.

This is fine for small apps and testing stuff, but increases the likelihood of name collisions and makes it harder to understand where code is coming from in larger apps.

If you want to do things the "right" way for a module system, you can access the exports of a module in the console with `require`:

```
> Todos = require('/lib/collections').Todos
```

Comment: I thought it might have to do with the capitalization, but was initially not getting different results when I would capitalize "Todos" in the console command. Also, in the lesson video and accompanying files the code was similarly disparate in capitalization.

However, now that I have added
`Todos = require('/lib/collections').Todos`
(minus the ">" at the beginning), it is working with the uppercase version of the command
`Todos.fetch().find()`. Much appreciated.

Comment: yeah there's a few bits here beyond the capitalization. Glad you got it working!